# The initial UICollectionView page is the second page instead of first page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uisplitview

I have a `UISplitView` like design (not really `UISplitView`, I used `View container` to mimic it).

The left side container has a `table view` and right side container has a `collection view`.

If I click the `tableview cell` in the left container, the right side `collection view` will be changed accordingly.

The `collection view` is paginated, it always has two pages.

If I scroll to the second page of the `collection view` and now I click a new `table view cell` in the left container, it will load the correct `collection view` in the right container, but it is in the second page instead of the first page!

I search around and could not find a solution.

I appreciate for any advices.

---

Update: Added related code.

Following code is in the `right container`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setup];
self.collectionView.delegate = self;

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
[self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.width) animated:NO];

}
```

The function `setup` is defined as following:

```
-(void)setup
{    
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.collectionView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
self.collectionView.bounces = NO;
self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting contentsize for collectionView?

Comment: I did not set contentsize. It uses the default one. I have figured out the problem. You are correct that I should use `[contentScrollView scrollRectToVisible:pageRect animated:YES];` to set the location. But I should NOT put it in ViewDidLoad. Since this is a delegate from the `left container`, I should put it in the `delegate` function. Then It works. Thanks!

Comment: Great that you got it. Actually, I have created a example for you. I am about to post it. But its good that you are able to resolve it.

Comment: It would be great if you can post your code. I am sure it will help me and others. :-)

Comment: I have edited my answer with example code and explanation. Please up vote it if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you write a code to scroll the scroll view to show the frame of the first page whenever user selects a row in left container.

```
[contentScrollView scrollRectToVisible:pageRect animated:YES];
```

Following is the example I have created to solve this issue :

You can download code form [Here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mlkpageviewcontroller)

After downloading source just add following method to MLKPageViewController.m

```
- (void)showPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if( index >= self.contentVCs.count )
        return;

    UIView *contentView = ((UIViewController *)[self.contentVCs objectAtIndex:index]).view;
    CGRect pageRect;

    if( mlkPageControl.currentPage == FIRST_PAGE || mlkPageControl.currentPage == LAST_PAGE )
    {
        pageRect = CGRectMake( (index * CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING) + index *  contentView.frame.size.width, contentScrollView.frame.origin.y , contentScrollView.frame.size.width, contentScrollView.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        pageRect = CGRectMake( (index * CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING) + index *  contentView.frame.size.width - CONTENT_VIEW_SPACING, contentScrollView.frame.origin.y , contentScrollView.frame.size.width, contentScrollView.frame.size.height);
    }

    [contentScrollView scrollRectToVisible:pageRect animated:YES];
}
```

Call above method from "ViewDidLoad" method of MLKPageViewController by passing page index.

Comment: I mean pageRect to be frame of first page. Did you tried that? If so, and not working then please post your code here. Will try to help you.

Comment: I have updated the post to add related code. Please let me know if you  need extra code. Thanks.